# Update main form after closing secundary form?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm working on a form to add new Customers. In this form the users selects an adress in a combobox (cbbAdress).
There's also a "new" button next to the adress combobox, which opens up a new form.

```
   frmAdres frmAdres = new frmAdres();
   frmAdres.Show();
```

In this form the users can add a new adress. 
When they close the form, the combobox (cbbAdress) doesn't update (obviously). 
I am wondering how I could make the combobox (cbbAdress) on the main form update?

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you code to something similar below:

```
using (frmAdres frmAdres = new frmAdres())
{
 if (frmAdres.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
   //Update your address here
   Address d = frmAddress.SelectedAddress;
 }
}
```

obviously you will need to ensure you set the DialogResult to OK on your address form when the Save button is clicked, and  add a property to the frmAddress form to read the selected address.

If you click close on the form and Dialog result is not 'OK' then the code in the 'if' block will not get hit.

Placing the form in a 'using' brace will also dispose of it after it leaves the context of the brace which will means you cant forget about disposing of it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ShowDialog()` ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Comment: @GregB - Yes - amended, just typed that code rather than copying from VS :p - thanks

Comment: @WraithNath Thanks! How do I set the DialogResult to OK on my address form?

Comment: @ThomasSchoof - Just before you call this.Close(); on the popup form, just set this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;  - If you click on close, then you can set dialog result to something else.

Comment: The garbage collector will dispose of the object as soon as it goes out of scope. Why do you feel it is neccessary to deal with it your self?

Comment: @Killercam - There could be references within frmAddress that reference an object that is still in use so the garbage collector wont be able to clean up the form, by calling dispose yourself you can add any additional code to the dispose method of the address form to clean up any references and events that are subscribed to. Additionally, consider code that is used in a loop for processing, but putting the objects in a using brace, then objects can be disposed of within the loop to keep memory consumption of the application down. I didnt used to do it when I started development but after

Comment: so many memory issues within CSV imports etc we as a team just dispose of objects as soon as they are finished with.

Comment: @WraithNath I am not sure I am with you. If you pass variables to a forms constructor `public f(var a, var b) { /*...*/ }` they are non-`ref` and will go out of scope as soon as the form does (i.e. when the form closed event is fired). Even if these were passed in as `ref` i.e. `public f(ref var a, ref var b) { /*...*/ }` this would still be the case or am I out-of-my-mind? :@

Comment: @Killercam - The garbage collector runs when it feels like it and does not always dispose when the method is left. the using brace means you can clean up memory, close streams and file handles etc when you want do (you can also just call dispose). More information here... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Pass to `frmAdres`'s constructor a reference to the parent form

```
frmAdres frmAdres = new frmAdres(this); 
frmAdres.Show();
```

in the constructor of the form

```
private MainForm mainForm;

public frmAfres(MainForm _mainForm) : this()
{
    this.mainForm = _mainForm;
}
```

(using this to call the default constructor). You can then access any control on your main form that has the appropriate accessor. So for your `ComboBox` in you MainForm you might have the constructor

```
public ComboBox myCombo
{
    get { retrun this.comboBoxName; }
    set { this.comboBoxName = value; }
}
```

then you could update just this control in your `frmAdres` class via

```
mainForm.myCombo.Update();
```

Alternatevly, you could just update the entire parent form from `frmadres` via

```
this.ParentForm.Update();
```

this should update your `ComboBox`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Make a Singleton :), with a Singleton you can share strings through classes.

```
public class MySingleton
        {
            private static Classes.MySingleton _mInstance;

            public static Classes.MySingleton Instance
            {
                get { return _mInstance ?? (_mInstance = new Classes.MySingleton()); }
            }

            private string _cbbadress;

            /// <summary>
            /// cbbAdress.
            /// </summary>
            public string cbbadress
            {
                get { return _cbbadress; }
                set { _cbbadress = value; }
            }
        }
```

Edit the string with:

```
        Classes.MySingleton.Instance.cbbadress = cbbAdress.Text;
```

EDIT: I've learned it this way, of course there are many other ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very usefull, I'll have to try it out! :)

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome :). BTW! You can put everything in a Singleton, even a button!